# Quartile for subgroups in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, statistics

I have a table with the times athletes of a sport club take to run a lap around the field . Each athlete has several entries in that table for each time they run and and for statistics purposed I need to gather some statistics regarding the time they take.

I already have the basic statistics like average time, median time, etc.... However I have no idea how to exactly do the bottom and top quartiles.

I see some examples for quartiles of a table if you just want the statistics of the whole table (in this case the whole club) but I have no idea how to make them for sub groups like distinct athletes of a table, could anyone give me point me on the right direction/give me an example?

The relevant data is in a very simple structure like this (there are more columns but in this case they don't matter)

```
LAP_ID | ATHLETE| TIME |
1      |  Ath_X | 120  |
2      |  Ath_Y | 160  |
3      |  Ath_X | 90   |
4      |  Ath_X | 80   |
5      |  Ath_Z | 113  |
6      |  Ath_X | 115  |
```

EDIT:There seems to be some misunderstanding, by Quartile I mean the 1st and 3rd Quartile, that is the place where it splits off the lowest 25% of data from the highest 75% and the place where it splits off the highest 25% of data from the lowest 75%.

Comment: can you please post the sample data. So that i can clear understanding

Comment: Sure, but the structure is very simple that's why I didn't mention it.Since it's literally just what I posted

Comment: Unlike median and mean, quartiles are ranges (as opposed to a discrete value). What data do you want from each quartile?

Comment: Ranges? To my understanding quartile is where the data splits. For example 1st Quartile is the place where you separate 25% of the data from the rest of 75%, while he median is actually the 2nd Quartile. I want to do the 1st and 3rd Quartile